# VPS - Few Questions from Real Beginner

Tags: linux, vps

As I'm real beginner I decided to go with managed services as recommended in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/166391/vps-administration-for-the-absolute-beginner) question, I already have a VPS with cPanel/WHM.

I'm planning to launch few startups - don't worry, I have funds for extend servers network, I have also possibility with my current host provider. However, I have few questions about such solution:
1. So far, I have 5 accounts on this VPS. I will not sell hosting - I'm just interested in hosting my personal project. Is it safe to host multiple websites (each website has separate account) on one VPS? Please note that one of my website is using APC to cache.
2. What would you recommend to secure /tmp partition?
3. Do I really need to install and configure iptables?

PS. What VPS suppliers would you recommend? My top priority is **security** and fully managed service. As you may see, I'm not a sys-admin, only a poor programmer ;)

Comment: The vps is typically unmanaged.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is safe to host multiple sites on one server / VPS.
2. How to secure your /tmp partition: http://www.webhostgear.com/34.html
3. Not required if you just need to host your websites on port 80 / 443